# Print Java Object data into server response as JSON String

Tags: java

I want to print custom authentication server response as JSON String. I tried this:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException {

//        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");

        ErrorDetail errorDetail = ErrorDetail.NOT_FOUND;

        ErrorResponse errorEntry = new ErrorResponse();
        errorEntry.setTitle(errorDetail.getTitle());
        errorEntry.setCode(errorDetail.getErrorCode());
        HttpStatus httpStatus = ErrorDetail.getHttpStatusBasedOnErrorCode(errorDetail.getErrorCode());
        errorEntry.setStatus(httpStatus.value());
        errorEntry.setDetail(ex.getMessage());
        Map<String, String> extra = new HashMap<String, String>();
        extra.put("detail", ex.getMessage());
        errorEntry.setExtra(extra);

        ErrorResponseDTO errorResponse = new ErrorResponseDTO();
        errorResponse.setErrors(Arrays.asList(errorEntry));
        response.getOutputStream().println(errorResponse.toString());
    }
}
```

I want to get readable JSON but I get this:

```
org.engine.exception.ErrorResponseDTO@28530766
```

Do you know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're print the object, not the message, could you try to use something like:

```
errorResponse.getDescription
```

Comment: Yes I want to print the object. How I can do it in human readable text (JSON)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
errorResponse.getDetail();
```

for further reference:

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/rs/exceptions/ErrorResponse.html#getDetail--